# SQL Error when adding primary key

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, executenonquery

When I attempt to add a new record and hence add a primary key, I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
>   HResult=0x80131904
>   Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Stock__BEAEB27A2652D17F'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Stock'. The duplicate key value is (39).

I am sure that the total number of records currently is 38. The primary keys are added from an array which all have numbers from 39-44.

I have attached the code below:

```
int y = 0;

SqlCommand orderCommand3 = new SqlCommand();

string conString3 = Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseEventsUnlimitedConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection connection3 = new SqlConnection(conString3))
{
    connection3.Open();

    while (ArrayCourseName[y] != "" && y <=5)
    {
        SqlCommand commandEvent = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO STOCK (IngredientID, IngredientName, StorageType, QuantityInStock, MinimumRequired) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5)", connection3);

        commandEvent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", ArrayIngredientID[y]);
        commandEvent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", ArrayCourseName[y]);
        commandEvent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", ArrayStorage[y]);
        commandEvent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", ArrayQuantity[y]);
        commandEvent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", ArrayMinimum[y]);

        int m = commandEvent.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (m != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Too many records changed");
        }

        i++;
    }

    connection3.Close();
}
```

Comment: Try making the primary key auto increment, you wont have to worry about adding them or duplicate keys anymore as the next number will be used automatically

Comment: you are using y and doing i++, how that is going to work, or its typo....i think it should be y++

Comment: @PranayRana has nailed it. You're not incrementing the right variable, so you are adding the same record in the array a second time, necessarily causing the index violation - and at precisely the location that would cause the error with the value you are observing. Great catch, pranay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you need to increment value of `y` not `i`, as you are using `y` as index value.

I suggest you make use of `for` loop will reduce complexity of your code

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++) {
 if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ArrayCourseName[i] ))
   break;
 ///rest of the code
 using (SqlConnection connection3 = new SqlConnection(conString3))
 {
    connection3.Open();
    // code for sql non execute 
 }
}
```

i suggest you make use of `using` connection and create connection object every time , because connection pooling will take care of pooling connection object every time.

Ref : [Is it better to execute many sql commands with one connection, or reconnect every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981376/is-it-better-to-execute-many-sql-commands-with-one-connection-or-reconnect-ever)

Comment: Have to wait a couple of minutes then of course if will!

Comment: @Bleari - i know my bad